# How to put these together and do I need a PWM expander?

Tags: avr, atmega, stepper-motor, l298

I'm having here

- an [`Atmega8`](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2486-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega8_l_datasheet.pdf)
- a [`PSM42BYGHW603`](http://www.pollin.de/shop/downloads/D310453D.PDF) stepper motor
- the [`L298`](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/L298_H_Bridge.pdf) stepper motor driver
- and the [`L297`](https://courses.cit.cornell.edu/ee476/FinalProjects/s2009/kk383_sl486/kk383_sl486/datasheets/l297.pdf) stepper motor controller

What I want to put those together such that I can control up to three [`PSM42BYGHW603`](http://www.pollin.de/shop/downloads/D310453D.PDF) stepper motors with my [`Atmega8`](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2486-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega8_l_datasheet.pdf) and I also want to avoid to waste too many pins on it.

I was thinking about an I2C-Slave that gets controlled by the master [`Atmega8`](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2486-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega8_l_datasheet.pdf). The question is if there is something like a PWM expander or if I should just use another [`Atmega8`](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2486-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega8_l_datasheet.pdf) as I2C slave? The thing is, I want to keep everything small, simple and inexpensive.

Would it be too if I asked for a circuit arrangement? I am quite a bit of a beginner regarding the creation of my own circuits.

Thank you for any help!

PS: I also have a [`MCP23S17-E/SP`](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21952b.pdf) but I was told that this wouldn't be useful here, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stepper motor drive circuit using the L297 and L298. It requires 5 I/O lines,  3 for stepping and 2 for limit switches. To control 3 motors you will need 15 I/O pins.

[RepRap Stepper Motor Driver 1.2](http://reprap.org/wiki/Stepper_Motor_Driver_1.2)
[image]

The MCP23S17 has 16 I/O lines so it should be be ideal for the job, provided that you don't want to dedicate the ATmega's SPI pins for something else. Otherwise you could use the I<sup>2</sup>C version (MCP23017) which is a bit slower but uses fewer pins.